# Change font color for part of text in editable combobox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to create a custom style or some event for combobox which will change a font color of some part of input text.

Exactly I would like to do something like this:
When we start input some charachters and we input "<" charackter color will change and when we close tag the color will change again for default.For example "asdsadsad<.*>asda"

Is there any possibility to create syntax highlight functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look around the [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit). It has the Syntax highlighting.

An Example can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor).